# [D3][SVG] zoom to object

Tags: svg, d3.js, zooming

could you please help me with zooming to SVG objects. no idea how to do this.
i need to zoom and center by click on object, i've made a test plunkr, so please take a look: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZQxhQ8VVoIXjMvdFIvQF
here's full code:

```
$(function(){
  svg = d3.select("#svg");
  svg_group = d3.select('#outer_group');

  zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .translate([0, 0])
      .scale(1)
      .scaleExtent([.5, 20])
      .on("zoom", zoomed);

  svg.call(zoom);

  function zoomed() {
    svg_group.style("stroke-width", 1.5 / d3.event.scale + "px");
    svg_group.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    $zoomService.$broadcast('zoom', {
        scale: d3.event.scale
    });
  }

  $('.sector').click(function(){
    //zoom to somehow??
  });
});
```

Comment: Only your code example about svg zooming helped me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [call `zoom.event`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior#event) explicitly on the correct element after setting the desired translation and scaling.

```
  var zoomed = false;
  $('.sector').click(function(){
    var bbox = this.getBBox();
    var scale = 4;

    // Manually calculating the position to which to transition to
    // Will differ on a case by case basis.
    svg
    .call(zoom
          .translate([ (- bbox.x - bbox.width / 2) * scale
                     , (- bbox.y - bbox.height / 2) * scale
                     ])
          .scale(scale).event
    );
  });
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/h1UP87dfQneRCFye9Xtu?p=preview

In the demo, I changed the position of the polygons and the `viewBox` on the `svg` to make it easier to calculate the exact coordinates to transition to for the zoom to stay centered. I also added some transitions and zoom-to-zero behavior not shown in the code excerpt above.

---

*Sidenote:* You don't have to use `jQuery` here to bind to `click` events; D3's `selection.on` can provide that function.

Comment: thanks. my main problem was in svg view box setup, i had no idea about negative x=width/2 and y=height/2 of viewbox for easy centering.